# Keyframe expand page on mobile device

Tags: html, css

Basically I have heading which change to other heading by scroll.

So first heading comes from left (outside of screen) to center of page and after few seconds it go to right (outside of screen) and then second heading come from left and so on.

It works correctly at desktop version ( http://two-house.com ) but on mobile device it makes page expand after animation of moving from center to right outside of screen.

HTML of that is:

```
<div class="slider__heading-container">
    <div class="item-1">
        <h2 class="heading-primary">
            <span class="heading-primary--left">
                Find your
            </span>
            <span class="heading-primary--right">
                perfect place
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        <h2 class="heading-primary">
            <span class="heading-primary--left">
                We will
            </span>
            <span class="heading-primary--right">
                suits your needs
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
        <h2 class="heading-primary">
            <span class="heading-primary--left">
                Invest and
            </span>
            <span class="heading-primary--right">
                earn money
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.slider__heading-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
    position: absolute;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
    animation-name: anim-1;
}
.item-2 {
    animation-name: anim-2;
}
.item-3 {
    animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    8.3%,25% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    33.33%, 100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% {
        transform: translateX( -100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    41.63%, 58.29% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    66.66%, 100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    74.96%, 91.62% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.slider:first-of-type {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? I don't have class named .slider

Comment: @BT101 inspect your code. You have `<header class="slider">`. Your `slider__heading-container` is set to move out of viewport, but none of the parents has any settings to keep the content at 100% of the viewport.

Comment: Look now it exapand slider to fit headers. Check it at mobile.

Comment: you've made it `width: 100vh` so basicaly a square (width = height) :) Should be `vw`.

Comment: It didn't help, take a look now

Comment: I just hide animation on mobile device for now I'll rewrite it later